# Question about diagonalizable matrix over C and R

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the matrix

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
  $$
(i) over $\Bbb C$,
(ii) over $\Bbb R$?

I just need verification for my answer. For this question I have identified the eigenvalues which are $\lambda=1,\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt3i−1),\frac{-1}{2}(\sqrt3i+1)$

This would make the eigenvectors be $v_1=(1,1,1), v_2 = (\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt3i−1), \frac{-1}{2}(\sqrt3i+1), 1), v_3=(\frac{-1}{2}(\sqrt3i+1), \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt3i−1), 1)$

Since 2 of the eigenvectors include complex numbers, would this mean that this matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ but not $\Bbb R$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, we need algebraic closure in order to find an invertible $P$ such that $P^{-1} AP = D$ where $D$ is diagonal in your case, and $A$ is *your* matrix above.

Hence this is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$, but not $\Bbb R$.